# Same Javascript code, unique outputs with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, obfuscation

I have the following Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() { 
    document.write("Hello StackOverFlow users!");
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

Is any recommended/fast way to encode/encrypt/minify/pack the JavaScript using PHP so the output be different every time (using a random string to pack the js or anything similar)?
I just want the same function, that would do the same thing every time but with different JavaScript code each time.

Comment: Randomize JS function behavior with PHP ? Use `if else ` to toggle through different functions that will do different things

Comment: @MeganFox The function is just an example to simplify the things. I have an entire js file that needs to do the same thing as now but with slight different code.

Comment: @dracosu what type of output you expect please give hint do you have a set of message array which should return randomly

Comment: @mamta It's not about the output, It's about the code. I want different JavaScript code each time to avoid some web spiders to identify the code pattern and modify/exclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most packers/compressors always use the same algorithm without any seed you might try to add some random js garbage before and after the function itself.

```
<?php
function getRandomGarbage(){
  return "\nfunction " . uniqid() . "(){}\n";
}
$myJsFunction = "... put your js here ";
//You can send the following to a php js compressor or pack it yourself
echo getRandomGarbage() . $myJsFunction . getRandomGarbage();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But, btw I'm looking to make unique snippets for an entire js file, not only one function. However starting from your suggestion I think that i can make it!

Answer (score -1):

Create random string function in PHP

```
<?php
/*
 * Create a random string
 * @author  XEWeb <>
 * @param $length the length of the string to create
 * @return $str the string
 */
function randomString($length = 6) {
    $str = "";
    $characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    $max = count($characters) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $rand = mt_rand(0, $max);
        $str .= $characters[$rand];
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Then modify your js function as follow

```
 <script>
    //assign php variable to js variable
    function myFunction() { 
        var randomString=<?php echo randomString(10);?>
        document.write(randomString);
    }
    myFunction();
 </script>
```

This will allow you to write random string each time JS function is called

[PHP function taken from 'https://www.xeweb.net/2011/02/11/generate-a-random-string-a-z-0-9-in-php/']

Comment: Hello Projesh, I'm looking to make an unique code snippet, not only a unique string so your solution isn't suitable for this problem.